# Javascript count percentage on 2 inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to count percentage in 2 inputs in two directions, when i wrote example in input number 1 value 100 in input number 2 that show value 80. And when i write in input number 80 that should in input number 1 value 100. That should work on all values etc. is there any pattern for this or other solution?

I mean 
When i write to input with name val1 example value 100 in input with name val2 value will be calculated example 100 - 20% = 80. And when i write to input with name val2 value 80 it should change value input with name val1 to example 100. That value what i wrote in input with name val2 should equal x(input name with val1) - 20% = val2(this value what i write in input with name val2).

my script

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="val1" />
    <input type="text" id="val2" />
</form>

document.getElementById( 'val1' ).addEventListener( 'input', function ( evt ) {
   document.getElementById( 'val2' ).value = percentage(evt.target.value.replace( ' ',  '_' ), -20 );
} );
document.getElementById( 'val2' ).addEventListener( 'input', function ( evt ) {
   document.getElementById( 'val1' ).value = percentage(evt.target.value.replace( ' ',  '_' ), 20.00 );
} );

function percentage(num, per)
{
  num = parseInt( num, 10 );
  return num+(per/100 *num);
}
```

Comment: Your Question is not clear. First why are you replacing

Comment: You could listen for the `input` event on the form element and use both input values in your callback. That way it will calculate either input regardless of which one you fill in.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier could you give me any link to example of this solution?

Comment: @SourabhSomani
I mean When i write to input with name val1 example value 100 in input with name val2 value will be calculated example 100 - 20% = 80. And when i write to input with name val2 value 80 it should change value input with name val1 to example 100. That value what i wrote in input with name val2 should equal x(input name with val1) - 20% = val2(this value what i write in input with name val2).

Comment: Your formula is wrong 100-20%=80 that is fine but 80+20% is wrong `80*20=1600` Now `1600/100` that is 16 means 80+16= Hope you are getting me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this. Please try this

```js
$("#val1").keyup(function(){
  if(+this.value) {
    let percent=+this.value*0.2;
    $("#val2").val(+this.value - percent)
  }
})


$("#val2").keyup(function(){
  if(+this.value) {
    $("#val1").val(+this.value/0.8)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="val1" />
    <input type="text" id="val2" />
</form>
```